# What's faster - a string split().contains() in my controller or in razor? ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a line of code in my razor that looks like this

```
@if(spaceEvent.RegisteredStudentIds.Split(',').Contains(@Model.MeStudentId)) {
   // show some specific HTML
}
```

Would it be faster if I removed the split and performed it in my controller?
I might even be able to do the .contains() in the controller was well!
Or in this case does it even matter?

Comment: Profile it. They also have different functionality. Splitting will not match `Rob,ert`, not splitting will.

Comment: See: [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). That said, if you want to check if one big string contains one smaller string at least once, you could check if [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k8b1470s.aspx) is zero or higher. (Less than zero means: not found).

Comment: Faster doesn't matter unless you have a demonstrable performance problem.  That being said, programming *logic* should occur in the controller and not in the view.

Comment: To me there's no overhead. Both parts are performed entirely on the server side in memory. Of course if you execute the same code against it. I may not have understood your question but the main concern was about executing it either on controller or razor view side right?

Comment: yes Jakub, that was my question. I just want to know if I should move the logic to my controller to help speed up the page load time?

Answer (score 0):

yes and no!
no because the `Split` has overhead. it should iterate thorough string, find characters witch matches with input, split and make and returns result array.

and yes because in a big string (100MB for example) the `String.Contains` should iterate thorough 100M characters, compares each by first char of input and next char... but when you have split the 100M in 200K words for example, the `IEnumerable.Contains` compares first word with input, if first char doesn't match it will skip other characters and goes to next word and goes 5 char later. in this scenario loop repeats 200K (depends to inputs) for example witch is less than 100M!
just if you have a big string and want use `Contains` method several times, Split it and keep result into an array, then use `array.Contains` method.